# Не получается записать данные в список Python

Tags: python, парсер, файлы, list

получаю определённый тип данных, и я хочу записать эти данные в список. Данные получаются в виде словаря. Ниже пример получаемых данны

```
[{'89756720.000.000014': ['5765675', '45654654']}]
[{'89756720.000.000014': ['5765675', '45654654', '876876687', '465465456', '234653454']}]
[{'36546524.101.889045': ['5765675', '45654654', '23423454', '543425786']}]
```

мой код записывает только один из данных из всего в таком формате:

```
{'36546524.101.889045': ['5765675', '45654654', '23423454', '543425786']}
```

Как видно в примере выше, записывает только последнее что выводит код. Мой ожидаемый результат:

```
[{'89756720.000.000014': ['5765675', '45654654']}, {'89756720.000.000014': ['5765675', '45654654', '876876687', '465465456', '234653454']}, {'36546524.101.889045': ['5765675', '45654654', '23423454', '543425786']}]
```

Сам код:

```
for profile_info in links_array:
    profile_response = session2.get(profile_info, headers=header).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(profile_response, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='list-view')

    new_datas = []
    for item in items:
        new_datas.append({
            profile_info: [item['data-key'] for item in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-key': True})],
        })

    for item in new_datas:
        with open('datas.txt', 'w') as out:
            out.writelines("%s\n" % line for line in item)
    codes_len += 1

    print(new_datas)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for item in new_datas:
    with open('datas.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.writelines("%s\n" % line for line in item)
```

Так вы перезаписываете файл на каждой итерации цикла. Поэтому сохраняется только последнее значение. Нужно делать наоборот - сначала открывать файл на запись, а потом уже делать цикл по коллекции:

```
with open('datas.txt', 'w') as out:
    for item in new_datas:
        out.writelines("%s\n" % line for line in item)
```